# viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear when using exit-segue

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, segue, unwind-segue

I have a table view with information, and a VC where I add information to the tableview. I have a modal segue to the information-adding VC, and go back to the tableview using a exit-segue.

When I do this, neither my `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear` methods get called. Why is this and what other methods can I use to reload the data I need to populate my table view with?

Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're doing wrong, because viewDidAppear should be called in this scenario. You can also use the IBAction method you had to create to make the unwind segue, to do anything you need to when coming back to this controller.

Comment: I don't know either, I have used the viewDidAppear with an unwind segue before. Anyways, the solution you provided worked :)

Answer (score 0):

`viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` will only get called when both view controllers are in same navigation stack. You should use `returnFromSegues` method to handle the things.